# Disabling a button defined in an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, button, anchor

I am using a fairly standard technique to create a button on my page using an anchor tag.
Specifically:

```
<a href="#" id="downloadBtn" onclick="doSomething()"><span style="margin-left:17px;">Download</span></a>
```

Initially I want to disable this button.   But because I implement it as an anchor tag, I don't know how to do this.   As a regular Input button, I would just add the attribute disabled=true, but what do I do here?

Thank you for your help.

Elliott

Comment: An A element with an *href* attribute and no *name* is a link, not an anchor. If you want a button, why not use a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, set `onclick="return false"`, then use your script to change the value of `onclick` when the time comes.

You could also add a class to the anchor, then use CSS to style the link so that it does not look like a link. Then remove that class from the element at the same time that you change the value of `onclick`.

Comment: Why bother adding a listener that does nothing? If the OP doesn't use a link (i.e. removes the href), the A element will only resopnd to a click if it has a listener. Which leads to asking: why is an A element being used at all?

Comment: He says that *initially* the link does nothing. That implies that later it does something.

Answer (score 1):

InOrder to disable it just remove your href and add it later using javascript:

HTML:

```
<a id="downloadBtn" onclick="doSomething()"><span style="margin-left:17px;">Download</span></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```